# Where to install Grub on a RAID0 HDD?

Tags: grub2

Where do I install Grub ? Here are the choices I have

```
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0              Linux device-mapper(striped)(3.0TB)
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p1            Linux device-mapper(linear)(786.4KB)
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p2            Linux device-mapper(linear)(314.6MB)            
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p2
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p3            Linux device-mapper(linear)(104.4MB)
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p3
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p4            Linux device-mapper(linear)(134.4MB)
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p5            Linux device-mapper(linear)(3.0TB)
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p5
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p6            Linux device-mapper(linear)(21.0GB)
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p6
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p7            Linux device-mapper(linear)(17.8GB)
/dev/mapper/isw_difechbgae_Volume0p8            Linux device-mapper(linear)(8.6GB)
```